# How to handle multiple opencv version in a c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to write a c++ code that can be build both in opencv version 3 and 4. But I found that `CV_BGR2RGB` in v3 is moved to `COLOR_BGR2RGB` in v4. I need that for an argument of `cvtColor` function.

In that case, how can I make it work in both version?

Comment: As an addition to [Nuzhnys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55492174/11089932): You'll also need two "configurations", since you may also have to include different headers, and link against different libraries. I just want to point out: Working with two different OpenCV versions isn't just editing some code.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
```

Complex:

```
#if (CV_VERSION_MAJOR >= 4)

    cv::cvtColor(..., cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);

#else

    cv::cvtColor(..., CV_BGR2RGB);

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I use the `cvtColor` multiple times, then should I copy that if-else phrase every time? I wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: Yes, copy-past. Or use include imgproc_c.h as simple decision